# Comparing models by R2 and RMSE

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation

I am developing model predictions using pls and h2o packages which lead to 2 models: pls.model and h2o.model. The R-square (square of pearson correlation) and RMSE for each round of cross-validation are shown below:
R2:

```
i     R2.PLS     R2.H2O
1   1 0.4415108 0.6232292
2   2 0.3754088 0.6056992
3   3 0.4267580 0.6204750
4   4 0.3505282 0.6062691
5   5 0.2870766 0.5344183
6   6 0.3858786 0.5794828
7   7 0.3449946 0.5692314
8   8 0.2974582 0.5522208
9   9 0.3446449 0.5694339
10 10 0.3987684 0.5561757
```

RMSE:

```
i  rmse.pls rmse.h2o
1   1  8.839967 40.99896
2   2  9.347349 29.94260
3   3  4.240366 14.75890
4   4 17.901563 29.89181
5   5  4.686803 66.04993
6   6 31.717909 10.28799
7   7  2.066342 32.74828
8   8 15.979214 21.05928
9   9 19.454079 10.88551
10 10 27.039400 68.27017
```

I am unable to explain why pls.model has lower R2 but lower error while h2o.model has higher R2 but high error. I checked the scatter plot but no non-linear pattern appear.
Would you have any thought of this? And in this case, what should be the better model?

Thanks
Phuong

Comment: I would interpret the result as `H2O` can better explain more variation on the dependent variable, while `PLS`, although explain less variation, generates prediction that overall closer to the actual values. You would get more help from https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @www: thanks, so which model would you choose for further prediction?

Comment: Still insufficient information to me. To your purpose, is it better to capture the trend, or it is more important to keep the prediction within a certain range? If it is the latter, I will use `pls`. But if it is the former, `h2o` may explain important trend in your data.

Comment: Please post at  stats.stackexchange.com with reproducible example dataset and more information. This site is for programming related question, while your question is not.

Comment: @www: I have justed moved the question to stack.exchange as you suggested. Thanks a lot. Hoping to get a better understanding on this.

Comment: Cross validation in rounds of training is good for tuning, but to finally pick a model you should be using a hold-out validation set that isn't seen by either model in training.